# Why is it necessary to "ignore" a level when applying sum contrasts?

Tags: r, matrix, categorical-encoding, linear-algebra, contrasts

I am confused about how sum contrasts are set up. As I understand, if I have some $K$-leveled factor, I can use sum contrasts to compare each level to the grand mean ($M_G$), effectively testing multiple hypotheses each predicting that some group $i$ of $K$ is different from $M_G$.

In practice (in `R`), when I create a contrast matrix for a 4-leveled factor by calling `contr.sum(4)`, I get:

```
contr.sum(4)
```

```
 1   0   0
 0   1   0
 0   0   1
-1  -1  -1
```

then when I invert it using `ginv` from `MASS` (adding an intercept column) to get a hypothesis table of mean weights, I get this:

```
ginv(
  cbind(1, contr.sum(4))
)
```

```
 0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25
 0.75   -0.25   -0.25   -0.25
-0.25    0.75   -0.25   -0.25
-0.25   -0.25    0.75   -0.25
```

which gives me 3 ($K - 1$) hypotheses, excluding the null. So, the first row (hypothesis) says that the weighted average of all 4 groups ($M_G$) is 0. Then, the second row says that $\frac{3}{4}M_1 - \frac{1}{4}M_2 - \frac{1}{4}M_3 - \frac{1}{4}M_4 = 0$, or equivalently that $M_1 = \frac{M_1+M_2+M_3+M_4}{4} = M_G$ and so on ($M_i$ is the mean of group $i$).

**However, there is no hypothesis comparing the mean of the 4th group, or in general the $K$th group. Why is that?. What if I wanted to specifically compare each group mean to the grand mean in my analysis?** I feel like I am missing something obvious here, as most resources I see on that simply mention that there are $K-1$ sum contrasts for a factor with $K$ levels.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121357/possible-to-code-contrasts-comparing-each-level-to-grand-mean-with-no-reference/411138#411138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked a lot here ... but mostly in the context of dummy encoding, see [Dropping one of the columns when using one-hot encoding](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231285/dropping-one-of-the-columns-when-using-one-hot-encoding)  and also [Removing intercept from GLM for multiple factorial predictors only works for first factor in model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215779/removing-intercept-from-glm-for-multiple-factorial-predictors-only-works-for-fir/218034#218034)   The underlying issue is the same when using `contr.sum` as it is in those posts where `contr.treatment` where used. Using your example, first, you can get a full contrast matrix with

```
test_full <- cbind(1, contr.sum(4, contrasts=FALSE))
 test_full
    1 2 3 4
1 1 1 0 0 0
2 1 0 1 0 0
3 1 0 0 1 0
4 1 0 0 0 1
 Matrix::rankMatrix(test_full)
[1] 4
attr(,"method")
[1] "tolNorm2"
attr(,"useGrad")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"tol")
[1] 1.110223e-15
```

(and, if you want you can trick R into using such a contrast matrix with `lm`, but then you get non-identifiable parameters). Continuing with your example,

```
test <- cbind(1, contr.sum(4))
myC <- MASS::ginv(test)
myC
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25
[2,]  0.75 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25
[3,] -0.25  0.75 -0.25 -0.25
[4,] -0.25 -0.25  0.75 -0.25 

solve(t(myC), c(-1, -1, -1, 3)/4)
[1]  0 -1 -1 -1
```

that way, you get your **missing contrast** for the fourth group as a linear combination of the four rows of `myC`:

```
-(myC[2, ]+myC[3, ]+myC[4, ])
[1] -0.25 -0.25 -0.25  0.75
```